# SSL error while connecting to WSO2 API Manager in Micro Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, sslhandshakeexception, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to publish the APIs to API Manager and whenever I start API Manager and then start the Micro Integrator I get the following exception in the Micro Integrator console. I am trying in my localhost. Because of this issue, Micro Integrator can't connect to the API Manager. Can anybody help me to solve this issue? I am using both API Manager and Micro Integrator v4.0.0

> ERROR {ServiceCatalogUtils} - Error occurred while reading the response from service catalog javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
> at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
> at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
> at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
> at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
> at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
> at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
> at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
> at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
> at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
> at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1572)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500)
> at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.utils.ServiceCatalogUtils.getAllServices(ServiceCatalogUtils.java:209)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.serviceCatalog.ServiceCatalogExecutor.run(ServiceCatalogExecutor.java:59)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:386)
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:291)
> at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:315)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:223)
> at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
> at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
> 23 more
> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:220)
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
> at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:381)
> 29 more
> Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
> at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:457)
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)

I tried various things to solve this issue like copy paste cert files and paste them. And also even generate self-signed certificates etc.

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the public cert of APIM to the client-trustore of MI in `<MI_HOME>/repository/resources`?

Also, are you running this on your local setup or in some setup in AWS, etc.? In such cases you might have to add the server certificate of AWS to the truststore of MI as well.